# In Docker for windows, how do i access a webapi running on my dev machine from the container i aslo have on my machine?

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker

I am currently running docker for windows  with a container using the asp.net core 2.0 image.

I also have a web api application running on iis on the development machine (the same machine i have docker installed with the container)

I need to be able to make an API request to the api on my dev machine.

I cant seem to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Update:

My docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY mysol.sln ./
COPY mysol.Web/mysol.Web.csproj mysol.Web/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/CraOrchestrator.Web
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mysol.Web.dll"]
```

I am running the container with

```
docker run -dit -p 1253:80 -v c:/data:/data --name sol mysol:latest
```

Comment: would you provide more details about the scenario? Is your container supposed to be the one performing the request to the Web API application in IIS? If so, would you post the .dockerfile you use to create the image and the settings you are to create and run the container?

Comment: see edits. thanks. The container is trying to perform the request to the api on the local machince

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problem for your containerised app to reach an app running on the host or even a different container. The problem may be in the .dockerfile.

You only need the executables in your image to correctly run your application. Your .dockerfile may look like:

```
# use microsoft dotnet core as base image - including ASP.NET Core
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.5-runtime

# set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy executables
ADD . /app

# make port 5050 available - should not matter much since this is a client app
EXPOSE 5050

# run app
CMD ["dotnet", "mysol.Web.dll"]
```

To create the image:

```
docker build -t app-image .
```

To run the container (and so your application):

```
docker run --name myapp -p 4000:5050 app-image
```

You may not require the port setup since the application you run is the one performing requests to the Web API running in IIS.